# AttributeError on supervision library

Tags: google-colaboratory, object-detection, attributeerror, yolo, roboflow

I am using yolo-nas object detection model from roboflow.

the training part was done seamlessly but in the last cells, it shows this error, i was expecting it to run without any problem but it says no attribute called "Dataset" in the module "supervision"

[here's the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwrW2.png)

Attribute-Error: module 'supervision' has no attribute 'Dataset'

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: That the code for whole cell among different cells of the model

Answer (score 1):

According to the official document,
Dataset API is still fluid and may change. If you use Dataset API in your project until further notice, freeze the supervision version in your requirements.txt or setup.py.

Now supervision0.8.0, "Dataset" may changed to "DetectionDataset".
Please try sv.DetectionDataset.from_yolo().